# Wordpress upload from localhost to server

Tags: wordpress

I uploaded my wordpress site from my Local host to a folder off my main domain (http://example.com/folder) using this tutorial http://www.webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/exporting-and-importing-wordpress/

(im working on a mac)

Everything went ok - admin panel is fine homepage is fine etc - only any page apart from the homepage redirects to this (http://example.com/folder/pagename) except instead of showing the content from that page it shows the unstyled information from the index page of my main root (http://example.com/)

What can I do to get this working?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do a general search with phpMyAdmin in your database for localhost URLs. And see [How to Find and Replace Text in WordPress MySQL Database using SQL When Changing Domains »  My Digital Life](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/04/23/how-to-find-and-replace-text-in-mysql-database-using-sql/) and [Search RegEx « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-regex/) for grepping through posts and pages.

Better yet, use [interconnectit.com WordPress Serialized PHP Search Replace Tool](http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/)

And check your theme files for hardcoded links (as opposed to links using [Template Tags/bloginfo « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Bloginfo)
) to style sheets and pages.

Reset permalinks in Dashboard/Settings/Permalinks.

Answer (score 0):

Check:

```
wp-admin > Settings > Wordpress address and Blog address
```

to include "folder"

Answer (score 0):

to get this working ... delete all the posts/pages - go to ur local wordpress blog and export it.
login to ur web blog and import.

that would be an alternative solution to working with the database and as far as i know exporting/importing content works good in wp :)